# Vue access unauthorized routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm not sure how this works, but I have this code to be executed before any redirect:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const publicPages = ['/auth/login1'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const auth: AuthStore = useAuthStore();

  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (authRequired && !auth.user) {
      auth.returnUrl = to.fullPath;
      return next('/auth/login1');
    } else next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

But when accessing the browser developer inspector, I can change this code and give access to any other route just changing the `publicPages` variable.

Comment: That's how client-side code works. What's the question?

Comment: SPAs are not sent piecemeal to the browser as needed.  From a network request, the entire app bundle is received.  There is no hiding it from users who want to go looking through it. If the question is, how to prevent access to restricted information, the answer is to only send restricted information from authorized API requests.

Comment: Please see the correct implementation here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/10/authentication-in-vue-js/ Instead of defining pages in beforeeach method, ask store for user authentication